# Python 2.7 OS X installer, mod_wsgi and Apache

Tags: python, mod-wsgi, osx-leopard

The Python 2.6 OS X installer didn't support 64 bit architectures, necessitating [some chicanery](http://groups.google.com/group/modwsgi/browse_thread/thread/cacddadc0c3c8e93/c92475afc0cc31eb?q=) to get mod_wsgi, Python 2.6 and Apache2 working on 10.5.

However, the [Python 2.7 OS X installer](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7/) does build a 'fat' Python install, so I'd like to know if anyone's tried this setup before I ditch my current Python 2.6 local setup, rebuild mod_wsgi with Python 2.7 and restore 64 bit Apache2? Given [the cautions](http://wiki.python.org/moin/MacPython/Leopard), that is (although I don't use IDLE).

Comment: I might add that this is to test Django apps locally with mod_wsgi.

Comment: I found this in the mod_wsgi list archives, which is slightly helpful: http://www.mail-archive.com/modwsgi@googlegroups.com/msg04854.html

Answer (score 1):

How to solve your problem:

- upgrade OS X to 10.6
- install macports and install any python distribution you like (you can have multiple installed)

PS. I use Python 2.7 with mod_wsgi on Apache (64bit)

Comment: Thanks Sorin - is that a local testing setup? Snow Leopard and Python 2.7 are inevitable (although Q was Oct 2010 and I *still* have one machine on 10.4!), but I tried and didn't like Macports - I'll probably use Homebrew (since I sometimes install to /usr/local already) http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/homebrew-os-xs-missing-package-manager/

Comment: @Dave I am aware about HomeBrew but I do not trust it for several reasons: the homepage is nice but is missing critical project information, like community links and bug tracker. Also on github the project is not migrated to an organization (multiple contributors). So I don't want to reply on one man maintaining an OS-like project.